# Xamarin.Forms listview and kitkat phone emulator

Tags: listview, android-emulator, xamarin.forms

I use VS 2015 to do a simple cross-platform app which contains a Xamarin.Forms listview and the listview data is bound to the results a C# call to a remote API web service. The call of that web api service just returns about 50 data rows and they will be shown gradually when user scrolls the listview down on emulators. I also use VS emulators for Android. The app works well with the 10.1" Marshmallow 6.0.0 xhdpi tablet API level 23 emulator. But it dies and closes itself in the middle of scrolling-down process for the 4.5" Kitkat 4.4 hdpi phone api level 19 emulator.

I do not know how the listview works with phone emulators. I am a newbie using Xamarin.Forms UI widgets. I guess the crash may relate to memory issue on the 4.5" Kitkat phone emulator, but I am not sure.

I caught some of crash logs by using Android Device Logging in VS as follows:

```
04-28 07:47:08.295 D/Mono    ( 1239): [0xb92a8220] hill climbing, change max number of threads 3
04-28 07:47:08.447 D/dalvikvm( 1239): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1124K, 19% free 5397K/6588K, paused 1ms, total 2ms
04-28 07:47:08.683 D/Mono    ( 1239): [0xb955cad0] hill climbing, change max number of threads 2
04-28 07:47:08.883 D/dalvikvm( 1239): GC_CONCURRENT freed 307K, 11% free 5924K/6588K, paused 0ms+0ms, total 1ms
04-28 07:47:09.999 D/Mono    ( 1239): [0xb92b3b00] hill climbing, change max number of threads 3
04-28 07:47:10.699 D/Mono    ( 1239): [0xb92a8220] hill climbing, change max number of threads 2
04-28 07:47:10.815 D/DonatelloNative_Selector(  133): Removing selector for fd 33
04-28 07:47:10.815 D/DonatelloNative_Selector(  133): Removing selector for fd 32
04-28 07:47:10.815 W/InputDispatcher(  464): channel 'b3268bf0 SchoolOfFineArt.Droid/md51c583ee22c53a99167a61678b0024deb.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
04-28 07:47:10.815 E/InputDispatcher(  464): channel 'b3268bf0 SchoolOfFineArt.Droid/md51c583ee22c53a99167a61678b0024deb.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
04-28 07:47:10.815 W/InputDispatcher(  464): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel 'b3268bf0 SchoolOfFineArt.Droid/md51c583ee22c53a99167a61678b0024deb.MainActivity (server)'
04-28 07:47:10.815 I/WindowState(  464): WIN DEATH: Window{b3268bf0 u0 SchoolOfFineArt.Droid/md51c583ee22c53a99167a61678b0024deb.MainActivity}
04-28 07:47:10.815 I/ActivityManager(  464): Process SchoolOfFineArt.Droid (pid 1239) has died.
04-28 07:47:10.815 W/ActivityManager(  464): Force removing ActivityRecord{b337aba8 u0 SchoolOfFineArt.Droid/md51c583ee22c53a99167a61678b0024deb.MainActivity t2}: app died, no saved state
04-28 07:47:10.859 D/Zygote  (  138): Process 1239 terminated by signal (11)
04-28 07:47:10.863 W/EGL_emulation(  663): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-28 07:47:10.863 W/InputMethodManagerService(  464): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 1239 uid 10087
04-28 07:47:10.867 W/Binder  (  634): Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.
04-28 07:47:10.867 W/Binder  (  634): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-28 07:47:10.867 W/Binder  (  634):   at android.inputmethodservice.IInputMethodWrapper.setSessionEnabled(IInputMethodWrapper.java:280)
04-28 07:47:10.867 W/Binder  (  634):   at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethod$Stub.onTransact(IInputMethod.java:129)
04-28 07:47:10.867 W/Binder  (  634):   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
04-28 07:47:10.867 W/Binder  (  634):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

The following are some codes of my app:

Xaml codes with listview widget:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:school="clr-namespace:SchoolOfFineArt;assembly=SchoolOfFineArt" 
             x:Class="SchoolOfFineArt.StudentListPage">
  <ContentPage.Padding>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" iOS="0, 20, 0, 0" />
  </ContentPage.Padding>
  <ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <school:SchoolViewModel />
  </ContentPage.BindingContext>
  <StackLayout BindingContext="{Binding StudentBody}">
    <Label Text="{Binding School}" FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Bold"
           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Students}">
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ImageCell ImageSource="{Binding PhotoFilename}" 
                     Text="{Binding FullName}" 
                     Detail="{Binding GradePointAverage, StringFormat='G.P.A. = {0:F2}'}" />
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

C# codes to call and parse XML results from the web api service:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using Xamarin.Forms;


namespace SchoolOfFineArt
{
    public class SchoolViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        StudentBody studentBody;
        Random rand = new Random();

        public SchoolViewModel()
        {
            string uri = "http://xamarin.github.io/xamarin-forms-book-preview-2" +
                             "/ElPasoHighSchool/students.xml";
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(uri);

            request.BeginGetResponse((arg) =>
            {
                // Deserialize XML file.
                Stream stream = request.EndGetResponse(arg).GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(StudentBody));
                StudentBody = xml.Deserialize(reader) as StudentBody;

                // Set StudentBody property in each Student object.
                foreach (Student student in StudentBody.Students)
                {
                    student.StudentBody = StudentBody;
                }
            }, null);

            // Adjust GradePointAverage randomly.
            Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1),
                () =>
                {
                    if (studentBody != null)
                    {
                        int index = rand.Next(studentBody.Students.Count);
                        Student student = studentBody.Students[index];
                        double factor = 1 + (rand.NextDouble() - 0.5) / 5;
                        student.GradePointAverage = Math.Round(
                            Math.Max(0, Math.Min(5, factor * student.GradePointAverage)), 2);
                    }
                    return true;
                });
        }

        public StudentBody StudentBody
        {
            protected set { SetProperty(ref studentBody, value); }
            get { return studentBody; }
        }
    }
}
```

C# code behind codes for the xaml page:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace SchoolOfFineArt
{
    public partial class StudentListPage : ContentPage
    {
        public StudentListPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about gradually, but it looks like they get created all at once after the call completes. Those 2 async actions are likely stepping on each other in the studentBody.Students: possibly adding to an enumeration in progress. Try to kick off the second async action only after the first one completes.